# What is the history of using $i$/$\iota$ as the imaginary unit?

Tags: mathematics, notation, complex-analysis

I'm interested in particular in knowing about when $\iota$ began to be used as the imaginary unit/who began to use it.

A majority of all text books that I have seen tend to just use $i$ as the imaginary unit. However, I remember being taught back in high school (in India) that the standard usage for the imaginary unit was $\iota$, which is most often just replaced with i everywhere. I can't find any source to back this up though --- for example wiki just says that $\iota$ is used when $i$ is being used for something else.

Am I remembering incorrectly? Was iota used initially historically maybe? Or is using iota just some notation that someone else tried to introduce? It definitely was/is considered valid notation if people are doubting the premise of the question (for example a quick search "imaginary unit iota" on Google comes up with several people using this notation. Even for example in the text that OP mentions [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/introduction-of-imath-and-jmath-notations-for-the-imaginary-unit) also talks about $\iota$ as valid notation.)

Comment: In *Introductio in Analysis Infinitorum* (1748) Euler still writes $\sqrt{-1}$, and according to [this answer](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/547/4201) he only later introduced the letter $i$ for the imaginary unit. I have not been able to find a scan of the document that shows Euler's first use of $i$. I have never encountered the use of $\iota$ instead of $i$, but am aware that $j$ is used instead in electrical engineering.

Comment: Was it $\iota$ (`\iota`) or $\imath$ (`\imath`)? ;) LaTeX, at the very least, clearly recognizes the latter as an alternative to $i$ :)

Comment: @njuffa - see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003972/did-euler-discover-the-eulers-identity) for scan of the non-use by Euler of $i$ for $\sqrt -1$...

Comment: For the first printed occurrence in Euler (1794, reprint of 1777 Euler's paper "*De Formulis Differentialibus Angularibus maxime irrationalibus quas tamen per logarithmos et arcus circulares integrare licet*," addressed to the 'Academiae') published posthumously in his [Institutionum calculi integralis](https://books.google.it/books?id=rCNRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA184), 2nd ed, vol.4, pp.183-194 : "formulam $\sqrt -1$ litera $i$ in posterum designabo".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you very much for the link to the scan in your second comment which clearly shows the use of $i$. I am puzzled by your reference to "non-use" in your first comment. Is that indicating disagreement with my statement about *Introductio in Analysis Infinitorum*? I was referring to e.g. [Lib. 1, p. 98](https://books.google.com/books?id=_zpRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: @njuffa - the linked post shows that Euler in his *Introductio* used $i$ but **not** to denote $\sqrt -1$...

Comment: @Danu: I was not aware of `\imath`! Thanks for that. So if not `\iota` at least I know that an "i without the tittle" is valid notation...

Comment: @njuffa: So I guess Euler used $i$ then. Who did start using $\iota$ (`\iota`) or $\imath$ (`\imath`) then?

Comment: In TeX, we use `\imath` for an *i* where we will put something above it, for example  $\hat{\imath}\; \check\imath\; \overline\imath$ ... but we don't use `\imath` by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an early occurrence of "iota", see :

- [Alfred Cardew Dixon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Cardew_Dixon) (English mathematician, 1865-1936), [The elementary properties of the elliptic functions. With examples](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/acq6963.0001.001/15?page=root;rgn=full+text;size=100;view=pdf) (London, 1894), p. 5 :

> **§10**. writing $\iota$ for $\sqrt {-1}$, [...].

Comment: Oh, this is almost exactly like the kind of thing I was looking for. If no-one else answers soon with maybe a discussion of an earlier source/if this is one of the earliest source using this, then I'll accept this answer.